# Is there a fast and robust way to unittest operations on files?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I’m writing a small pywin32 program that converts text files to docx/pdf and that’s all chill and working. BUT… I haven’t figured out a way to unittest the coverter that would not require creating tempfiles. The proccess is really slow.
Is there a commonly accepted good practice on unittesting operations on files?
The converter + unittests below.

```
# file converter.py
import win32com.client as win32


class Converter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word = win32.Dispatch('Word.Application')
        self.word.Visible = False
        self._word_format = {
            'docx': 12,
            'pdf': 17
        }

    @property
    def word_format(self):
        return self._word_format

    def open_and_close(func):
        def wrapper(self, fpath):
            doc = self.word.Documents.Open(str(fpath))
            doc.Activate()
            func(self, fpath)
            doc.Close()
        return wrapper

    @open_and_close
    def to_docx(self, fpath):
        new_fpath = str(fpath).replace('.doc', '.docx')
        self.word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(new_fpath, FileFormat=self.word_format['docx'])

    @open_and_close
    def to_pdf(self, fpath):
        new_fpath = str(fpath).replace('.doc', '.pdf')
        self.word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(new_fpath, FileFormat=self.word_format['pdf'])

    def __del__(self):
        self.word.Quit()

# file test_converter.py
import unittest
import tempfile
import os
from pathlib import Path

from converter import Converter


class TestConverterToDocx(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.converter = Converter()

    def setUp(self):
        self.tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        for _ in range(5):
            tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=self.tempdir.name,
                                        suffix='.doc', delete=False)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.tempdir.cleanup()

    def test_to_docx(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.tempdir.name):
            for file in files:
                self.converter.to_docx(str(Path(root) / file))
        files = [file for file in os.listdir(self.tempdir.name)
                 if file.endswith('.docx')]
        self.assertEqual(len(files), 5)

    def test_to_pdf(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.tempdir.name):
            for file in files:
                self.converter.to_pdf(str(Path(root) / file))
        files = [file for file in os.listdir(self.tempdir.name)
                 if file.endswith('.pdf')]
        self.assertEqual(len(files), 5)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to test. Either you mock all file system calls that you don't want to be called in your test (that depends on the implementation of the converter), or you use something like `pyfakefs` to mock the complete file system . In this case you also have  to be provide fake files with a contents the converter can work with.

Comment: Im pretty sure that the Word application does the converting well. I wanted to test if it actually finds the files within a directory and after converting names the files properly.

Comment: You are not testing if the converter finds the files in a directory, as you traverse the directory in the test yourself and feed the file name to the converter. So it would be the same to only test one file. Apart from that, I suspect that it is slow because of the calls to the word API, not due to the file system access.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the help :)